# How to Insert Multiple Checkbox Values into a Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been working on this and searching the Web and coming up empty for the better part of two days.  With a lot of sweat, I can insert one checkboxed value into a DB; however, if I check more boxes, it will still only insert one value.

Here is my code I'm using on input user page (with form tags excluded):

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="1"> ActionScript<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="2"> AppleScript <br />
```

Now I'm grabbing two session variables to make link the selected skill to the user who is logged on:

```
  $skills = $_POST['skills'];
  $id = $_SESSION['Ind_ID'];
```

**Here is the code that there is some small error in:**

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($skills);$i++) {
    // echo $skills[$i];
    $query= "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID) VALUES (" .$skills[$i]. ",
            ".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";
 }
```

With my echo $skills[$i] I can see that I am looping and can display as many user inputs to the screen; so, that is the good news.

The **issue** is I can't get it to **insert more than one value into a DB**.  I can do one value at a time; but, no more than one.

It seems my query is pretty close.  It works perfect if I choose to select only one checkbox; however, if I select more than one, it only inputs the last value (so, if I have 10 values selected, it will insert the last value into the DB).

Any help, much appreciated.

I'm using PHP and MySQLi

**UPDATED BASED ON FEEDBACK FOR LOOP**
Here is the updated loop.  I have the query outside the loop, and now trying to APPEND to my initial query.  Error says something is wrong with the syntax of the query.

```
$query= "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID) VALUES (" .$skills[$i]. ",
                                                        ".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";

  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($skills);$i++) {
  //echo $skills[$i];
  $query.= " VALUES (" .$skills[$i]. ",".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";
  }
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use a prepared statement and bind the skills_id variable.

Comment: Thanks....Will make those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what your code is doing. Each loop, you're redefining the `$query` variable, so that when you get to the end, the final value of `$query` will be the last think you checked.

If you still want to use the same loop logic that you have written, which is probably not the most efficient way, then you'd have to execute the query each time *within* the loop, so that each query you write will be executed.

More precisely, the confusion seems to be stemming from the fact you haven't quite discovered the difference between assigning a value to a variable and passing a variable to a function for execution.

Comment: Great.  You have explained the **why**.  Any ideas on how to make this code more efficient (the looping through each does not sound efficient at all).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Begin the `$query` text outside of the loop `$query= "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID)`, then, in the loop, recursively append to the `$query` variable: `$query .= "VALUES (".$skills[$i]. ",".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")"`. You'll have to make sure you get the syntax correct with your loop logic.

At the end, you'll have all values in a single `$query` variable, ready to add to the database.

Comment: very interesting approach.  I'll have a go at it now.  Very much appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: if you have time, could you point me in the right direction (link) for how to append to the $query.  So much appreciate this.

Comment: I've update my original question at the bottom with my loop code.  Error says syntax.  Hate to bother you again.  I just know I'm so close.  Hate to give up.

Comment: For one, the original definition of `$query` needs to not add any values, since at that moment, `$i` is undefined. The other issue as I loosely talked about, is that each `VALUES (...)` needs to be separated with commas, so it's up to you to get the looping syntax correct

Comment: you are a genius...I just have to add the comma if more than one skill, and then delete the last comma.  One value is inserting so once I get the comma figured out, it will be working.  Thank heavens you were online and you decided to help.